# Error 248 in android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

while connecting the sensor simulator with emulator in android, the sensor simulator data not displayed. in logcat it shows

> host ERROR/Hardware(241): Don't know about host: 192。168。0。9 : 8010.

Answer (score 0):

I've also met that problem, I guess the problem are these strange dots, that cause parsing error. Changing emulator to another version (with normal dots ;)) resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also foud that bug. Mateusz was right. It's becouse of dot.
To not install another Emulator you can just switch keyboard layout to "Android Keyboard".
Long press on text field and switch from Hieroglyphs (at least it was in my case) to AK.